# Can WH_MOUSE catch global events?

Tags: c#, wpf, setwindowshookex

I'm trying to develop a WPF C# application that captures mouse clicks even (especially) if it's in background in order to start another task.

On MSDN documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx ) I can read that WH_MOUSE should have either a global or thread scope.

I instantiate my hook handle this way:

```
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,
                        MouseHookProcedure,
                        (IntPtr)0, 
                        AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
```

where MouseHookProcedure is the delegate of my callback function and WH_MOUSE value is 7 (following Winuser.h).

The code works but it can only catch local clicks (I just need WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages), the clicks inside the window. I need to catch clicks also outside the window, and when the window is in background.

I tried hooking to WH_MOUSE_LL (with a value of 14), but it's not working.

For the most part I followed this: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804
with some changes since I am using WPF and not WinForms.

The documentation about Hooks is a bit confusing. 
All in all I'd like to know:

- Can WH_MOUSE detect mouse messages globally? If yes, what am I doing wrong?
- Can I hook from a .NET C# code to a WH_MOUSE_LL? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You posted the wrong code.  What you have now is entirely normal, your hook can only see mouse messages that go to your window.  You really do need WH_MOUSE_LL to catch-em-all.  Google is filled to the brim with examples on how to do that.

Comment: I got it working now with WH_MOUSE_LL.
Previously I was googling for a way to use Hooks on Mouse and since MSDN doc stated the WH_MOUSE worked on Thread / Global I followed their example. When I tried using the WH_MOUSE_LL within their example it didn't work anymore. So I was trying to understand which path I should've followed. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with WH_MOUSE_LL and you need it.

In my case I developed a global keyboard maybe this could help you.
I needed to call [LoadLibrary](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.loadlibrary) in the third parameters.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

 void MyFunction(){
     [...]
     SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProcedure, LoadLibrary("user32.dll"), 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be able to have a global mouse hook implemented in C#. You would then pass zero as the last arguments to SetWindowsHookEx and your hook procedure must reside in a DLL, not an EXE. That's because the DLL will be injected into every process that has windows belonging to the same desktop as the hooking application. For this same reason writing global hooks in .NET is not actually recommended by most because it causes the CLR to be loaded into every desktop process, which can carry substantial overhead.